# Magento module:uninstall orphans any dependencies (required modules)

Tags: magento2, composer, cli, dependency, uninstall

I have some modules that are dependent on a core module. When I use the command

`composer require stti/module-catalogbook`

Magento installs 2 modules.. Stti_Catalogbook and Stti_Catalogcore.  If i then run

```
magento module:uninstall Stti_Catalogbook
```

Magento uninstalls the Catalogbook module, executing the routines to update the attributes and stuff i wrote, and removes the code from the vendor/stti directory. It also removes the Catalogbook entry from magentoroot/composer.json. Something odd it does however, is remove the entry from magentoroot/composer.json for the Catalogcore module.

I then run

```
magento module:status
```

It shows that Stti_Catalogcore is still in the list, and enabled.

At this point, Catalogcore cannot be uninstalled. I get a message in red declaring Stti_Catalogcore is not an installed composer package when i run

```
magento module:uninstall Stti_Catalogcore
```

FYI, i'm using satis to work with my local repo.  I don't think this is causing the problem however.

Here is the code from Catalogbook/composer.json

```
{
  "name": "stti/module-catalogbook",
  "description": "Configures magento for CRM catalog book product type",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "100.0.0",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "My Real Name",
      "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Stti\\Catalogbook\\": ""
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "stti/module-catalogcore": "100.0.0.*"
  }
}
```

Here is the code from Catalogcore/composer.json

```
{
  "name": "stti/module-catalogcore",
  "description": "Core module for catalog CRM catalog integration",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "100.0.0",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "My Real Name",
      "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Stti\\Catalogcore\\": ""
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't really know the `module:uninstall` command but does it also do the composer removal? My guess is it would be "hard" to check that required module is not used by something else, though I have not looked into the commands myself.

Comment: You could always add this on https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Answer (score -1):

to uninstall module please rn below command :

> php bin/magento module:disable Package_Namesapce